# Copying a file from one directory to the next and changing the name

Tags: linux, shell, cp

If I wanted to copy a file called myscript from, let's say "/home/myusername" to a directory called "/home/myusername/test" while also renaming it to myscript2... how would I do that?

I tried cp myscript /test but received the error: cannot stat 'myscript': No such file or directory

Help? And thank you in advance.

Comment: It means that `mysript` is not in your current directory as it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cp` takes a one or more files as source and a destination.  The if the destination is a filename and not a directory, and there is only one source file then the file is renamed.

```bash
$ mkdir /tmp/a /tmp/b
$ echo test > /tmp/a/somefile
$ cp /tmp/a/somefile /tmp/b/          # creates /tmp/b/somefile
$ cp /tmp/a/somefile /tmp/b/somefile2 # creates /tmp/b/somefile2
```

Comment: So I'm still not following. I have a directory called testwork08 and a file in there called cd8.sh. I'm trying to copy that file over to testwork09 while also renaming the file to cd9.sh. I keep getting an error: cp: cannot create regular file '/testwork09/cd9.sh' : No such file or directory

Comment: @ReneRojo Is there a directory called "/testwork09/"?   I don't think so.    If you are copying individual files, then you will have to manaully create the directory first, then you can copy and rename the file. so `mkdir /testwork09/` then `cp /testwork08/cd8.sh /testwork09/cd9.sh`.

Comment: There was. I figured it out. Thanks @toppk. As you can tell, i'm super new at this but I enjoy it and really want to learn.

Comment: @ReneRojo no worries, there's a bit of a learning curve but you'll be proficient soon enough.  you probably want to learn about relative vs absolute paths, `..` and `.` directories.   i think every person using unix has at one point or another deleted or overwrote files by accident.  I recommend getting a backup system in place as soon as possible.  you will be very happy to have it.

Comment: thank you!! I'm taking a class and have several books. Baby steps.... Thank you for all future help

Comment: @ReneRojo If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Done. Thank you!